# Triangle with sides a,b,c and area

Tags: geometry, area

There is a triangle with sides $a,b,c$, then his area is:

**a)** $A$ not greater than $\frac{1}{2}(a^2-ab+b^2)$

**b)** $B$ greater than $\frac{1}{2}(a^2-ab+b^2)$

**c)** $C$ greater than $\frac{1}{2}(a^2-\frac{1}{2}ab+b^2)$

**d)** $D$ less than $\frac{1}{2}(a^2+ab+b^2)$

I am thinking about applying the Heron formula here, because we know all its sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

The area is $\displaystyle\triangle= \frac12ab\sin\gamma$

As $\displaystyle 0<\sin\gamma\le1, ab\sin\gamma\le ab\iff -ab\sin\gamma\ge -ab$

$\displaystyle\implies A-\triangle=\frac{a^2-ab+b^2-ab\sin\gamma}2\ge\frac{a^2-ab+b^2-ab}2$ which is $\displaystyle\frac{(a-b)^2}2\ge0$

Comment: @Gregor, nice to hear that. I was going add the last case in the answer:)

Comment: according to my calculations answers $A$ and $D$ are correct, am I right?

Comment: @Gregor, I would say nothing more than Now, $$\displaystyle D-\triangle=\frac{a^2+ab+b^2-ab\sin\gamma}2 $$  $$=\frac{a^2+b^2+ab(1-\sin\gamma)}2\ge\frac{a^2+b^2}2\ge0$$

Comment: Method used is neat.

Comment: Yes I had exactly the same result, but should not be $\displaystyle\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}>0$ because we know that $\displaystyle a,b>0$ ? Then there would be $\triangle<D$

Comment: @Gregor, agreed

Comment: OK, thank you very much!